# node js performance for the individual user

Tags: node.js, multithreading, event-loop

A lot has been said about the high performance of node js, when compared to the multi-threaded model. But from the perspective of a single user, an http request is made, a db operation is issued, and the user will have to wait till the response from the database arrives. Sure, the event loop can in the meantime listen to other requests, but how does the individual user feel the speed benefit when it is the IO operation that takes most of the time?

Comment: Really? Just re-read your question and think about what you just asked.

Comment: i mean... a request can only be as fast as the io operation it requires... that has little to do with nodejs

Answer (score -1):

From de user perspective the performance will be the same. But imagine a site that receive millions of request, the server would stuck, because the resources of the server are limited. With node it is possible improve the power of the server, because node will optmize the way that resources will be accessed, using queues with events, saving memory usage and put to cpu to work heavy.